# Retrieve Spark Mllib StringIndexer column mapping

Tags: scala, apache-spark, apache-spark-mllib, apache-spark-ml

How do I get the mapping out of a trained Spark MLlib StringIndexerModel?

```
val stringIndexer = new StringIndexer()
    .setInputCol("myCol")
    .setOutputCol("myColIdx")
val stringIndexerModel = stringIndexer.fit(data)
val res = stringIndexerModel.transform(data)
```

The code above will add a `myColIdx` to my DataFrame mapping values in `myCol` to an index based on the values frequency. i.e. Most frequent value -> 0, second most frequent -> 1, etc...

How do I retrieve that mapping from the model? If I serialize/deserialize the model, will the mapping be stable (i.e. Am I guaranteed to same result after the transform)?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

`StringIndexerModel` exposes the mapping using `labels` attribute:

```scala
stringIndexerModel.labels: Array[String]
```

where values correspond to consecutive labels for example for:

```scala
val data = Seq("foo", "bar", "foo", "bar", "foobar", "bar").toDF("myCol")
```

you'll get following `labels`:

```scala
import org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString

Array(bar, foo, foobar)
```

with `bar` indexed as 0.0, `foo` as 1.0 and `foobar` as 2.0. This is property of the model and is preserved when model is `saved`.

When used in `Pipeline` you can also use [`IndexToString`](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.ml.feature.IndexToString) which will use column metadata to map indices back to labels.

```scala
indexToString.transform(stringIndexerModel.transform(data)).show
```

```
+------+--------+-------------+
| myCol|myColIdx|myColReversed|
+------+--------+-------------+
|   foo|     1.0|          foo|
|   bar|     0.0|          bar|
|   foo|     1.0|          foo|
|   bar|     0.0|          bar|
|foobar|     2.0|       foobar|
|   bar|     0.0|          bar|
+------+--------+-------------+
```

Comment: Thanks! Is there a way to fit stringIndexer, further customize mapping then apply customized mapping for transforming?